# Is this what a 0.1 layer height should look like?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

I've done 0.1 before and I think I've gotten better and more smooth results than this:

[image]

I think that my printer is having some sort of problem, or the print bed it too low because this was printed at a 0.1 layer height. I think the print should look a lot more smooth than that. I'm using the Monoprice Select Mini.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right, looks like the Z-step is larger than 0.4mm. You may need to do some calibration if you haven't yet since you said the bed was low.

Comment: Could you perhaps include some textual description of what is in the image? The current title (and wording) of your question is not very friendly to search machines or visually impaired users. Also, it would be helpful to mention the scale of the object (since that would affect whether or not this is "normal").

Comment: Have you checked to see if your X-Y gantry system is properly tightened? This looks almost like your layers are shifting in Y while printing. Forward for one layer then slightly shifted back for the next layer.

Answer (score 4):

This may be an effect of the not using a "Magic Number" for your layer height. The Monoprice Select Mini has a z-resolution of 0.04375mm, so layer heights should be multiples of that. (See [What are the “magic numbers” on a Monoprice Select Mini?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/what-are-the-magic-numbers-on-a-monoprice-select-mini))

If you slice with a layer height of 0.1mm, each layer will be a little smaller (0.0875mm) or bigger (0.13125mm) to get close the the ideal height. The extrusion won't change, causing some layers to be thin and overextruded and others to be thick and underextruded.